# Mailgun is not reaching the last echo/test statement (PHP/Ubuntu setup)

Tags: php, ubuntu, mailgun

I'm new to PHP and was trying to do a Hello World for Mailgun to see how it works. For some reason the last two `echo`s are not called and the email is not sent. See my code below:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';  
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.

$domain = //
echo("TEMP");


# Make the call to the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun("key-###");
echo("TEMP");

$cont = array(
'from'    => 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandboxc73bdba03d4f4a46a36c319de9e2c00e.mailgun.org>',
'to'      => 'ovadia <oharary@me.com>',
'subject' => 'Hello',
'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
 );


 $result=$mgClient->sendMessage($domain, $cont);

 echo("TEM2P");

 echo("TEM3P");

 ?>
```

Error Logs:

```
[Fri Dec 26 13:31:49.740756 2014] [:error] [pid 17630] [client 73.197.216.144:49648] script '/var/www/html/temp.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Dec 26 13:33:02.652593 2014] [:error] [pid 18741] [client 73.197.216.144:49737] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\\Common\\Exception\\RuntimeException' with message 'The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle.' in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php:72\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php(28): Guzzle\\Http\\Client->__construct('https://api.mai...')\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(26): Mailgun\\Connection\\RestClient->__construct('key-54065c15441...', 'api.mailgun.net', 'v2', true)\n#2 /var/www/html/temp.php(15): Mailgun\\Mailgun->__construct('key-54065c15441...')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php on line 72
```

Comment: Do you have error logging set up on your sever? If so, what errors do you see in the logs?

Comment: And the error logs had the answer...was missing phpcurl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start bu installing PHP curl: `sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl`. Then check to make sure that your scripts are able to find all of their resources. You have an error in your stack trace that indicates that /var/www/html/temp.php can't be found potentially.

Then `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` and try your code again.
Good luck.